# Return all the values of a specific index number

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For example, from this dictionary:

```
dictionary = {"one":["a","b"],"two":["c","d"],"three":["e","f"]}
```

I would like to return all the values at index 1: `("b", "d", "f")`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict.values`

```
>>> d =  {"one":["a","b"],"two":["c","d"],"three":["e","f"]}
>>> [i[1] for i in d.values()]
['f', 'd', 'b']
```

But as dictionaries don't maintain order, the list will not be in order.

For this particular example, `sorted` works out well

```
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted(d.values())]
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d =  {"one":["a","b"],"two":["c","d"],"three":["e","f"]}
i = 1

[d[key][i] for key in sorted(d) if len(d[key]) > i]
```